# Is there a way to define a local variable in a changeset? (Not a changelog level property)

Tags: liquibase

I have a *Liquibase* changeset that executes a *PostGIS* executable command in order to convert a *shapefile* (GIS file) to a table.

```xml
<!-- Will execute :
export PGPASSWORD=postgres

shp2pgsql 
   -s 4326 -I /data/comptes-france/territoire/2016/communes.shp
   public.communes_2016 | psql -d comptesfrance -U postgres -h localhost 
-->
<changeSet id="shp2pgsql_communes_2016" author="mlebihan" failOnError="false">
    <comment>Importation des shapefiles des contours des communes 2016</comment>
    
    <executeCommand executable="export">
        <arg value="PGPASSWORD=postgres"/>
    </executeCommand>
    
    <executeCommand executable="shp2pgsql">
        <arg value="-s"/>
        <arg value="4326"/>
        
        <arg value="-I"/>  
        <arg value="/data/comptes-france/territoire/2016/communes.shp 
             public.communes_2016"/>  

        <arg value="|"/>
        <arg value="psql"/>  

        <arg value="-d"/>  
        <arg value="comptesfrance"/>  

        <arg value="-U"/>  
        <arg value="postgres"/>  

        <arg value="-h"/>  
        <arg value="localhost"/>  
    </executeCommand>
 </changeSet>
```

As you read, it's plenty of mentions of `2016` year.

- In its `<comment>`.
- in `data/comptes-france/territoire/2016/communes.shp public.communes_2016`, where it appears two times.

Is there a way to declare a local variable in a changeset, so that I can use a `$year` or something else, to avoid repeating `2016` everywhere?

This variable has to be only local to that changeset, because next changeset will be willing to do the same, but for `2017` and so on, (and maybe, in a later question, I will ask you about the ability to perform a *for* loop, if this question receives a positive answer).

Comment: AFAIK, there's not such feature as neither changeSet level variable, nor changeSet for-loop